# Make npm script receive dynamic values using json or env file

Tags: javascript, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a npm script to help deploying react apps (using create-react-app), but I need to set the S3 bucket url string on a env or json file, so I can use it for multiple buckets without changing the package.json script content. I honestly looked everywhere but didn't managed to make it work yet.

Does anyone have some clue if this can be done, or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using an external javascript file:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy:staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging node ./scripts/deploy.js",
    "deploy:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./scripts/deploy.js"
},
```

scripts/deploy.js

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const env = require('./env.json')

const ls = spawn(
    `yarn build && aws --profile XXXXXX s3 sync build s3://${
        env[process.env.NODE_ENV]
    }`,
    { shell: true },
)

ls.stdout.on('data', (stdout) => console.log(stdout.toString()))
ls.stderr.on('data', (stderr) => console.log(stderr.toString()))
ls.on('close', (code) => console.log(`Closed ${code}`))
```

env.json

```
{
    "staging": "STAGING_URL",
    "production": "PRODUCTION_URL"
}
```

Not the prettiest, but works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can read any json file via require in your node script. Let's say you have the following "my_settings.json" file:

```
{
    "bucketName": "test_dev"
}
```

And the node script that looks like this:

```
var settings = require("./my_settings.json");

console.log(settings.bucketName);
```

If you run it (assuming that both these files are in the same directory), you will see the bucket name "test_dev" in console.

So you will be able to get settings and organize your build process depending on them.

Comment: I need to access the variable inside tha package.json file, like this:

"deploy:staging": "yarn build:staging && aws --profile XXXXX s3 sync build s3://$BUCKET_URL"

Comment: Hm... maybe this package will help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var